# Returning true or false in JQuery in a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a string of text in a element, what is the most efficient way in jQuery to return if that text matches a given string.

E.G,

```
<div id="myDiv">This is a test</div>

$("#myDiv").eq("This is as test"); // returns true or false
```

But eq is not the right function

Answer (score 9):

jQuery:

```
$('#myDiv').text() === "This is as test";
```

Note, this gets ugly if the DOM contains other nodes or weird spacing, etc. But for simple nodes you control, that's the simplest way.

Comment: But jquery == javascript @naveen

Comment: @11684: jquery is just a javascript library. the above code needs jquery reference. And I was merely mentioning to remove the first line

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the grammar31 solution myself, but just for fun, here are some other ways:

```
$("#myDiv:contains('This is a test')")​.length​==1;
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML == 'This is a test';
```

Comment: +1 for the first one. But could you explain that one? Is that cross-browser?

Comment: They should both be cross-browser as far as I know, the second is plain JS.

Comment: Yes, from CSS-tricks.com: _:contains is deprecated in CSS, but still works in jQuery._

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#myDiv").text() === 'This is a test'){ /* true */ }else{ /* false /* }
```